# add text or image to Craft Commerce confirmation email through the CMS

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I have a customer that wants to modify the order confirmation email.  I set up a new Entry for order confirmation to include a content block that goes to the email/email_confirmation file.

When I check in the browser or preview it works perfectly. When I actually send the email it doesn’t appear.

1) It works in the browser with:

```
{% if entry.basicContentBlocks %}
// html code
{% endif %}
```

2) The Commerce plugin only seems to read from information in Commerce.  I tried to pull in the data:

```
{% set emailEntry = craft.entries.section('emailConfirmation') %}
```

3) I tried making a global variable that used the email confirmation entry:

```
{% set emailBlock = craft.globals.getSetByHandle('emailBlock') %}
```

It seems the email is loaded and sent before the entry information.

Is there a work around to allow customers to add information or pictures from the CMS?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: You can definitely load entries in a commerce email. Not really sure what errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the emailConfirmation was only one entry it was an array.

```
{% set emailEntry = craft.entries.section('emailConfirmation').first() %}
```

setting up the entry to the html was similar to what I thought, but I didn't include the ".first()" so I wasn't getting what I expected.